# Sharepoint2013 REST: How to handle problematic characters in GetByTitle('') list title?

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint, ecmascript-6, sharepoint-2013

I'm using the `/lists/GetByTitle('')` endpoint quite heavily and have encountered a problem when the list title contains a problematic character(s).

I would prefer not to have to strip the characters during list creation but rather leave intact if possible.

Example addresses: `/lists/GetByTitle('Domino's')` and `lists/GetByTitle('Custom Scores / weights test')`.

What is the correct way of handling this?

For clarity's sake, my code is:

1. Creating the list.
2. Attempting to create a list item by POSTing data to `/lists/GetByTitle('{title}'/items`.

The method I'm using to create ListItems in step2 is embedded within a module that I would prefer not to have to modify. It's unfortunately tightly coupled and changing everything to use List GUIDs or Internal Names, would be a large amount of work that I can't afford right now.

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this problem was to URI encode the list title and duplicate apostrophes.

```
export const listURI = title => `/lists/GetByTitle('${encodeURI(title).replace(/\'/g, "''")}')`;
```